# How to change the font size of QTableWidget header?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to decrease the size of the font in horizontal header of a QTableWidget. Below code does not work, font size remains unchanged.

```
QFont font;
font.setPointSize(7);
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setFont(font);
```

How can I change the font in this case?

Comment: Weird, this _should_ work, and it definitely works for me. Are you sure the horizontal header isn't modified anywhere after? Maybe it has a stylesheet assigned?

Comment: I am using Qt 4.8.1 and there is no stylesheet used on tableWidget.

Comment: I, like @SingerOfTheFall, cannot reproduce this on Qt 4.8.0. Please provide source code that reveals more details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically there are two ways:

(1) I am not 100% sure why your code is not working, but my guess is the font you created is invalid and won't apply, usually you want to use the existing Font from the QHeaderView, manipulate it and reset it to ensure that all other settings are identical:

```
// Example 1
QFont font = ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->font();
font.setPointSize( 42 );
ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setFont( font );
```

(2) Further you can use StyleSheets instead of QFont which is often easier.

```
// Example 2
_ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView { font-size: 42pt; }");
```

Both ways have worked with Qt-4.8.3

Comment: Solution on PySide6, self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("QHeaderView { ffont-size: 42pt; }")